# Prove the inequality $\frac{x}{x+1}<\ln(x+1)<x$ for $x>0$

Tags: calculus

> Prove $\frac{x}{x+1}<\ln(x+1)<x$ for $x>0$

What I have done is to look at the derivatives and interval of each function.

lets: $f_1=\frac{x}{x+1}$ , $f_2=\ln(x+1)$, $f_3=x$

the intervals of the functions are $f_1=(0,1)$ , $f_2=(0,\infty)$, $f_3=(0,\infty)$

now looking at the derivatives of the functions $f_1'=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$, $f_2'=\frac{1}{x+1}$ , $f_3'=1$

Is this enough to prove the inequalities? is there a way to use the mean value theorem or Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Comparing the derivatives *is* using the mean value theorem.

Comment: consider the functions $ln(x+1)-\frac{x}{x+1}$ and $x-ln(x+1)$, and note that their derivatives are always positive. to show that they are positive at $x>0$, just put $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that $x<(x+1)\ln(x+1)$ for $x>0$. This equivalent to showing that $x<(x+1)\ln(x+1)$. Taking the derivatives of both sides, we find that $1<\ln(x+1)+1$ for all $x>0$. The rest of the argument is easy.

Comment: How have we ended up with just one inequality?

Comment: The other one can be done by considering $x-\ln(x+1)$, as mentioned by Jane.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(x+1) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{t+1} > \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{x+1} = \frac{x}{x+1}.$$